# JavaScript circular (?) assignment explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone please explain, in simple words, how the following JavaScript statement works. Much obliged

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Comment: There is no circular assignment here. `var MongoClient` is a [variable declared in the current context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), `.MongoClient` is a property of the default value [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)-ed by the `mongodb` module. Completely different items.

Comment: There's nothing circular. It's getting the `MongoClient` property from the import and assigning it to a local variable with the same name. There's no other relationship between the names. `var obj={foo:"bar"}; var foo = obj.foo;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require('mongodb')
```

Imports all of the exports from the `mongodb` package

```
.MongoClient;
```

Extracts just the `MongoClient` property from the exported Object

```
var MongoClient =
```

Assigns a reference to the `MongoClient` object to a local variable which also happens to have the name `MongoClient`